# How can I give an element "animation-name" attribute with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation

Firebug tells me

> InvalidCharacterError: "String contains an invalid character
>   newImage.setAttribute('-webkit-animation-name','spawns');"
>   newImage.setAttribute('-webkit-animation-name','spawns');

My code spawns images randomly on the screen. Everything is working fine except this.

Comment: *"...or something like that..."* No. Tell us **exactly** what it's saying. Copy and paste, even. There's just no reason to be vague about error messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because in HTML attributes are strictly defined. Thus none of them start with an hyphen.

What you want is `newImage.style.webkitAnimationName='spawns'` or  `newImage.style.setProperty(-webkit-animation-name', 'spawns')`.